# Como gerar o build de aplicativo ANDROID no IONIC

Tags: android, ionic, react-native, build

Digitei o comando `ionic cordova build android`  e o resultado foi esse no prompt

```
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for android
```

> ionic-v1.cmd build
>   ionic-v1[3676]: c:\ws\src\node_contextify.cc:635: Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
>    1: 00007FF7092DC6AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
>    2: 00007FF7092B7416 node::MakeCallback+4534
>    3: 00007FF7092B74CF node::MakeCallback+4719
>    4: 00007FF70928B7C0 node::DecodeWrite+13120
>    5: 00007FF7097E4382 std::vector >::_Umove+79442
>    6: 00007FF7097E54E9 std::vector >::_Umove+83897
>    7: 00007FF7097E482C std::vector >::_Umove+80636
>    8: 00007FF7097E474B std::vector >::_Umove+80411
>    9: 000002EFEC85C5C1
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-v1.

```
    ionic-v1.cmd build exited with exit code 134.
```

Estou com um problema similar ao tentar rodar o aplicativo direto no telefone

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

---

Meu `ionic info`

```
    Ionic:

   Ionic CLI         : 5.0.2 (C:\Users\DEV02\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.1.0
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (11 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.4

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Encontrei a resposta nesse link: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3462

Answer (score -1):

talves você precise adicionar a plataforma caso não tenha adicionado, com o comando:

`ionic cordova platform add`

Comment: Não,eu adicionei e removi a plataforma...fora o link que postei acima, meu sdk estava configurado de maneira errada.